# How to upload files to a website. using python

Tags: php, python, file-upload, web-crawler

It is creating a program that automatically uploads files to the VirusTotal site to receive test results.

With Python Selenium, Crawling succeeded. However, uploading the file failed.

How do I upload files automatically?
I am sorry for my lack of English skills.

ps. I want to solve the problem with Python instead of php. I don't know Php well. But if I have to use a php, I will learn.

[image]

Comment: "With Python Selenium, Crawling succeeded. However, uploading the file failed." We need to see the code you tried for uploading the file, or we cannot tell you what is wrong with it.

Comment: Oh, I got you. I will post the post including the code again. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using send_keys in Selenium:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(upload file xpath)
# maybe like this: //input[@type="file"]
element.send_keys("your file path")
```

And if you use Firefox, you should make 'input' element visible first.

---

You can use Explicit Wait to wait for element until visible.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 'your xpath')))
```

Comment: An error has occurred. what is this??

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "**my program path**", line 10, in <module>
    file_input = browser.find_element_by_xpath('**full upload file xpath**')

Comment: File "C:\Users\**my name**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)

Comment: File "C:\Users\**my name**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']

Comment: File "C:\Users\**my name**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

Comment: File "C:\Users\**my name**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"**full upload file xpath**"}
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90)

Comment: T^T

I think webdriver can't found Element

Comment: @im_student Hi, I edited my answer. If still failed, you can paste xpath and html code.

Comment: I think the Virustotal site is hiding html. When I tried the same thing on another website, I realized what the problem was when I interpreted the error and the problem didn't find xpath on the Virustotal site.

Your help really helped me.